# using external project asp.NET user control (ascx) in Visual WebPart

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, mvp, ascx

I'm new to sharepoint2010, I'm used to ASP web development.
What I'm doing is referencing a .ascx from an external project as described in this Scott Guthrie article :
http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx

and also this article for MVP in SharePoint:
http://www.henrycordes.nl/post/2009/04/29/Model-View-Presenter-design-pattern-in-Sharepoint.aspx

I have a test web application which has a project reference to the webControls (Ascx) library project and there is a prebuild line that copies over the ascx to a folder in the web application project.
Then I reference the ascx control from the aspx page as per normal!

BUT in SharePoint I try the same trick and get this error :

" Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The referenced file '/UserControls/Calculator.ascx' is not allowed on this page."

In fact the path to the ascx is not being parsed at all, because if I change to a nonexisting directory I get the same error. Or if I copy the ascx to the '14' directory.

What steps do I need to take to get this ascx deployed in SP2010?

here is the lines I'm using to refrence the ascx in sp visual webpart code aspx page:

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="sjb" tagName="calc" src="~/UserControls/Calculator.ascx" %>
<sjb:calc ID="calc" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to deploy the control to the _layouts/controltemplates directory. That will get them deployed to the farm safely.

The best thing for you to do is to add a visual webpart to your project as an example and replace the example ascx file with yours.

Then in your masterpage/page like this

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mfKA" TagName="KeepAliveControl" Src="~/_controltemplates/LoginKeepAlive/KeepAlive/KeepAliveUserControl.ascx"%>
```

Comment: How would I replace the webpart ascx with mine ? Except copy/paste? The reason I am creating a usercontrol library outside of the SP project is for testability, and should make development of user controls more simple.

Comment: Do you want to use it in a web part, or just have the control available for registered use on a master page/page layout?

Comment: In visual studio, click add in your project, then SharePoint/Usercontrol. This will add a control to the controltemplates folder. Name this control the same name as your control and then replace it with yours. This will put the <TemplateFiles> attribute into the package manifest file.

<TemplateFile Location="ControlTemplates\SharePointProject\UserControl1.ascx" />

That should get it into SharePoint for you.